# Calculate interest rate of mortgage payment in python

Tags: python, math, annuity

I am trying to compute the interest rate of mortgage in python .

I have below formula.
a/{[(1+r)^n]-1}/[r(1+r)^n]=p

Here I have the value for a ,n , p.

is it possible to calculate r using these values in python.
Any pointers will help.

Comment: if you cannot solve it for `r` yourself, let `sympy` try. Have a look at `solve` from `sympy.solvers`. This [example](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#algebraic-equations) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Sympy package which could help.

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve(x**2 - 1, x)
```

Replace x**2 - 1 by your equation with respect to r (shift p to the left side).